# Git does not track changes in virtualenv

Tags: python, git, macos, virtualenv

I am using MacOS Monterey 12.3.

Once I initialize git for my Python (Python3.9) project, if I set up virtualenv, all of the sudden, git can no longer track any changes made in the given directory.

To see if initializing git and virtualenv in the same directory causes any issue, I first created a directory "directory_above" and ran `git init` there. Then, I created a sub directory "directory_below" in "directory_above", and I set up virtualenv in the sub directory. Even without activating vurtialnenv in the sub directory, git cannot track any changes made in the directory. `git status` simply gives me

> nothing to commit

As far as I remember, this kind of setup worked fine before, and recently, git started to fail to work with virtualenv.

Has anyone encountered the same issue in the past? If so, how did you solve the issue? I spent some time looking the same issue and solution, but I couldn't find it on here.

Comment: I know it doesnt solve the problem, but what happens if you first set up the env and then initialize git?

Comment: Please include an exact sequence of commands to reproduce this. (I tried to reproduce, but failed.)

Comment: Note that it's normal to *not* want any `.venv/*` files to show up in Git. I can't tell from your question whether you mean that the `.venv` files are not showing up, or that you mean that when you active the virtual environment, something *else* that *was* working, stops working. As @TurePålsson said, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for the late response, everyone. I was caught up with some stuff, and I just read all the comments above. Actually, Anthony's answer helped me solve the issue, so I will just accept his answer. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it sounds like you ran `virtualenv .` -- but you probably want `virtualenv venv` or some other subdirectory

`virtualenv` writes a `.gitignore` file which contains the following contents:

```
$ cat venv/.gitignore 
# created by virtualenv automatically
*
```

that `*` there will cause all of the contents to be ignored

either delete that file (not recommended) or make your virtualenv in a subdirectory of your project